# How can I use relationship with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My database stockcomment table as below;

```
id|user_id|stock_id|comment
1 |   10  |  9034  |RC MONSTER CAR
2 |   1  |   9034  |very cool car
```

My databese user table as below;

```
id |user_name           |
1  |   Ufuk ÇAĞLAR      |
10 |   Mariana Atencio  |
```

How can I relate to each other.

How to access user information with comments?

I want to do output :

```
[{"id":1,"user  _id":1,"stock_id":9034,"comment":RC MONSTER CAR,"user_name":"Ufuk ÇAĞLAR",
 "id":2,"user  _id":10,"stock_id":9034,"comment":VERY COOL CAR,"user_name":"MARIANA ATANCIO",]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `User` and `Stock` models and `users`, `stocks` and `stockcomment` tables, you can set a relationship from your user model

```
public function stock() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Stock::class)->withPivot('comment');
}
```

Then in your stock model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)->withPivot('comment');
}
```

Then you call them:

```
$stock = User::find($id)->stock; //Stock from this user
//or
$users = Stock::find($id)->users; //Users from this stock
```

**EDIT:**

> How to access user information with comments?

With using `Query Builder`:

```
$data = DB::table('stockcomment')->where('stock_id', 9034)->get();
```

or if you have `StockComment` model and a relationship towards `Stock` on it, you can do:

```
$data = StockComment::where('stock_id', 9034)->get();
```

`$data` will be:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,"user_id":1,"stock_id":9034,"comment":RC MONSTER CAR,"user_name":"Ufuk ÇAĞLAR"
   },
   {
       "id":2,"user_id":10,"stock_id":9034,"comment":VERY COOL CAR,"user_name":"MARIANA ATANCIO"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define `User` Model and `StockComment`

now in User model.

```
public function stockComments(){
   return  $this->hasMany(StockComment::class);

}
```

Now you can access User object with `$user->stockComments`

Here is an example

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->stockComments;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: for example stock_id = 9034. get comments and user infoes?

Comment: @ufuk   you have to create another relationship

Answer (score 1):

Define this relationships in `StockComment` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And this relationship in the `User` model:

```
public function stockComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockComment::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

On the User model, you need to create a hasMany relationship.

```
public function stockcomments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockComment::class);
}
```

Once created, you'll be able to fetch the comments by doing

```
$user->stockcomments;
```

This will return a Collection which will allow you to iterate through

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins to achieve desire result, here is your updated code

```
$result = User::join('stockcomment', 'users.id', '=', 'stockcomment.user_id')
->select('users.id', 'stockcomment.stock_id', 'stockcomment.comment',stockcomment.username)
->get();
```

Comment: Can not be done with Laravel Relationship? İs this possible?

Comment: yes you can do that in laravel find detail here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins